# Div table hover change page color instead of just div

Tags: html, hover

**I'm sorry, I'll ad the code again here.**
I use div to make a table, and one a cell change background color on hover.
But when mouseover on a cell, the background of the page change instead of just that div cell.
Also the, table is not 100% width of browser.

Please help me.

```css
    .container {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    <!--background-color: salmon;-->
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    
}

.cell1 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.cell2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.cell3 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.cell4 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}
.cell5 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.cell6 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.container span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2098d1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover:before, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus:before, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 
  <div class="cell1 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">
   <span><img src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/male-avatar.jpg" /></span>
   <span>
    Giám Đốc Điều Hành<br>
    Call: 0916.3232.19<br>
    minhkhangjsc@gmail.com<br>
    <a href="skype:minhkhangjsc?chat">
     <img style="float: left;" src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/skype.png" width="70" />
    </a>
    <a href="ymsgr:sendim?minhkhangjsc&amp;m=Chào bạn, tôi muốn tư vấn về sản phẩm">
     <img style="float: left; margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;" alt="Mr. Hải" border="0" src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=minhkhangjsc&amp;m=g&amp;t=2&amp;l=us" />
    </a>
    <br>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell2 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">
   <span><img src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/male-avatar.jpg" /></span>
   <span>
    Phòng kinh doanh - Mr. Trí<br>
    Call: 0919.911.955<br>
    tri.nk@minhkhangjsc.com<br>
    <a href="skype:kazihaha?chat">
     <img style="float: left;" src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/skype.png" width="70" />
    </a>
    <a href="ymsgr:sendim?kazihaha&amp;m=Chào bạn, tôi muốn tư vấn về sản phẩm">
     <img style="float: left; margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;" alt="Mr. Trí" border="0" src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=kazihaha&amp;m=g&amp;t=2&amp;l=us" />
    </a>
    <br>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell3 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">
   <span><img src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/female-avatar.jpg" /></span>
   <span>
    Phòng kinh doanh - Mr. Trí<br>
    Call: 0906.430.277<br>
    phuongtrang_minhkhangjsc@gmail.com<br>
    <a href="skype:nguyen.trang669?chat">
     <img style="float: left;" src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/skype.png" width="70" />
    </a>
    <a href="ymsgr:sendim?minhkhangjsc_mayhuygiay&amp;m=Chào bạn, tôi muốn tư vấn về sản phẩm">
     <img style="float: left; margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;" alt="Ms. Trang" border="0" src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=minhkhangjsc_mayhuygiay&amp;m=g&amp;t=2&amp;l=us" />
    </a>
    <br>
   </span>
  </div>
  
 </div>

 <div class="row">
 
  <div class="cell4 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">
   <span><img src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/male-avatar.jpg" /></span>
   <span>
    Giám Đốc Điều Hành<br>
    Phone & Mail<br>
    Mail<br>
    Image<br>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell5 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">
   <span><img src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/male-avatar.jpg" /></span>
   <span>
    Giám Đốc Điều Hành<br>
    Phone & Mail<br>
    Mail<br>
    Image<br>
   </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell6 hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">
   <span><img src="http://sieuthithietbivanphong.com/image/male-avatar.jpg" /></span>
   <span>
    Giám Đốc Điều Hành<br>
    Phone & Mail<br>
    Mail<br>
    Image<br>
   </span>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No code, no answer. Please add code (**not links**) in your question.

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code

Comment: I changed it. So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS doesn't yet have the parent selector. What you are trying to do is, change the `body` (parent) of the `<div class="sidebar-link">`, when it is hovered `:hover` event or pseudo class. This is not possible even in CSS 3. It is **not possible** using CSS alone.

You may need to use JavaScript / jQuery for this.

**JavaScript**

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-link");
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onmouseover = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = '#999';
  }
  divs[i].onmouseout = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-link");
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onmouseover = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = '#999';
  }
  divs[i].onmouseout = function () {
    document.querySelectorAll("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}
```

```css
#side-menu {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  height: 100%;
}

#search-container {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar-link {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;

}
div.sidebar-link:hover{
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
```

```html
<div id="side-menu" class="sidebar-nav span2">
  <div class="sidebar-link"><span>Link 1</span></div>
  <div class="sidebar-link"><span>Link 2</span></div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9v8hn143/**

**jQuery**

```
$(".sidebar-link").mouseover(function () {
  $("body").css("background-color", "#999");
}).mouseout(function () {
  $("body").css("background-color", "");
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(".sidebar-link").mouseover(function () {
  $("body").css("background-color", "#999");
}).mouseout(function () {
  $("body").css("background-color", "");
});
```

```css
#side-menu {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  height: 100%;
}

#search-container {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar-link {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;

}
div.sidebar-link:hover{
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="side-menu" class="sidebar-nav span2">
  <div class="sidebar-link"><span>Link 1</span></div>
  <div class="sidebar-link"><span>Link 2</span></div>
</div>
```